# Botman, powered by dialogflow, is not replying to my messages

Tags: php, laravel, dialogflow-es, chatbot, botman

I am learning how to create Dialogflow based NLP chatbot using PHP and Botman.io . I wrote a simple code that should be working, but the botman is not replying to my messages.

I have walked through the documentation and official online course from botman.io , but it did not help because they have the exact same code.

Please take a look at my code botman.php file, if it is not hard:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\BotManController;
use BotMan\BotMan\Middleware\Dialogflow;
use function GuzzleHttp\json_decode;
use BotMan\BotMan\Interfaces\Middleware\Received;

$botman = resolve('botman');

$dialogflow_token = 'it is secret'

$dialogflow = Dialogflow::create(dialogflow_token)->listenForAction();

$botman->middleware->received($dialogflow);

$botman->hears('weathersearch', function($bot){

    $extras = $bot->getMessage()->getExtras();
    $location = $extras['apiParameters']['geo-city'];

    $url = 'http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=38b39a718abc4c6da25112826190108&q='.urlencode($location);
    $response  = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

    $bot->reply('The weather in' . $response->$location->$name . ', ' . $response->$location->$country . 'is: ');
    $bot->reply($response->current->condition->text);
    $bot->reply('Temperature: '.$response->current->temp_c. ' Celcius');

})->middleware($dialogflow);


?>
```

The bot should be responding to the messages like "what is the weather in California" by giving current weather temperature and condition, i.e 25C Sunny

Answer (score 1):

you can try this
https://github.com/genkovich/DialogFlowBotManMiddleware

but you have to switch on API v2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the dialogflow api and integrate the botman with the dialogflow, follow these steps given in the link below, it works for me.

[Integrate Botman with Dialogflow](https://github.com/genkovich/DialogFlowBotManMiddleware)

However, there's still problem like the botman cannot go to the right intent, and it only go to the default welcome and default fallback intent only. To solve that problem I add 'input.unknown' to the others intent and write the code in botman like below:

```
$dialogflow = DialogFlow::create('en');
$botman->middleware->received($dialogflow);
$botman->hears('(input.*)', function ($bot) {
 $extras = $bot->getMessage()->getExtras();
 $bot->reply($extras['apiReply']);
})->middleware($dialogflow);
```

for more discussion regarding the topic you can view it on the link given below.

[Adding input to hears and dialogflow intent](https://github.com/botman/botman/issues/873)